# You've been matched! vs Finish your profile

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

In the Job preferences, I have selected *Open, but not actively looking*
(Fewer matches. Employers can find you and we'll be selective with the *matches we send*)

When I open [developer story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/10961238), on the right side I can see *You've been matched!* and list of suggested jobs appears. On the bottom of the list, there is  Finish your profile. *Once finished,* ***we'll start matching*** you with jobs that you'll love!

I think it's not necessary to *finish* the profile as I am already getting the matches for jobs. So here what does it mean *Once finished, we'll start matching you with jobs that you'll love!*, should it be simply **finish the profile** or something more relevant.

[image: You've been matched example]

[image: Finish your profile example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We've tweaked the copy a little bit to make the intend clear. Thanks for flagging.